# Random .r files created when using Jenkins and SVN

Tags: android, svn, build, jenkins, dropbox

I've got an automated build system from my Android project using Jenkins which syncs via SVN.
Occasionally I get new files added to the workspace which I assume are from the SVN process that are collisions.  When this happens in the resource folder it causes a build failure as the file extensions are stripped and there is a name space collision.

e.g.

```
 [aapt] res\drawable\icon.png.r584:0: error: Resource entry icon is already defined.
 [aapt] res\drawable\icon.png:0: Originally defined here.
 [aapt] res\drawable\icon.png.r588:0: error: Resource entry icon is already defined.
 [aapt] res\drawable\icon.png:0: Originally defined here.
```

Any ideas why I'm getting these r584, r588 files?  Probably more importantly, how do I stop this from happening?

Whilst the jenkins build is local to the machine, the original SVN directory I work in is inside a dropbox managed folder (don't ask!).  Whilst I don't think this is a problem I feel I should mention it just in case it does have a contributing factor.

These .r??? files don't exist in my original source tree or SVN structure so can only be made by the SVN syncing operation done by Jenkins as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have said, *.rNNN are SVN merge conflicts, where NNN is the revision number that is in conflict. Again, like others have said, Jenkins must be the owner of the workspace, not something else.

Let me just try to clarify something here. You said `"the original SVN directory I work in is inside a dropbox managed folder (don't ask!)."`. Are you saying that:

a) You are using a custom workspace for Jenkins (you would have had to muck around with custom workspace settings for that)
b) Your (user's) working directory is a dropbox managed folder

If b) is true, that's OK. But if a) is true, this may cause all sorts of problems. If this is the case, you really need to let Jenkins manage its own workspace. Yes, that may mean double the space-requirements, but this is the way it should be.

Now, assuming that Jenkins's workspace is managed by Jenkins, the first thing it will try to do is `SVN Update`. This should never cause merge problems (those *.rNNN files), unless something is modifying the workspace. Again, if point a) is true, consider giving Jenkins it's own workspace. The build itself could be modifying the workspace (I am not familiar with Android builds or what it does with files).

In either case, what you want is to do a clean SVN checkout. There are two options that will work for you.

- Always check out a fresh copy
- Use svn update is much as possible with 'svn revert' before update

Both of these are found in the job configuration, under "Source Code Management", under "Check-out Strategy".

The first will clean the Jenkins workspace and do a full checkout. This may be longer, but "cleaner".

The second will try to revert any local changes to the workspace before doing an SVN update, thus eliminating the merge conflicts.

Comment: Thanks Slav, yes it's option b.  I think it's that revert part that will solve all my woes.. Thank you!

Comment: AHH!! Thank you, yes it was because I generate icon.png via part of the ant process which is why it marks it as a conflict on subsequent builds.

Comment: @sradforth  In general, if it is generated, it should not be part of the SVN repository.  You might want to consider removing it.

Answer (score 3):

they look like conflict markers - when you merge, if it cannot automatically resolve the issue, it will put 2 temp files in the directory with the revision numbers as part of the file extension. You're supposed to use a diff app to decide what the final file should look like and then tell svn you've resolved the conflict. SVN will then delete the old temp files and let you commit your change.

Your commits will have garbage in them today - if you look at the file of the same name, you'll see diff markers embedded in the source. I'm surprised you can commit at all, but I guess the dropbox copy is somehow affecting the situation - are you committing deltas or just checking in the directory as if it was a bunch of new files?

Comment: Thanks, I think you're absolutely right.  It is just deltas and must have been another process 'touching' the files that is causing this... If I could tick all the answers I would!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the *.r### files are, like you suggest, when there is a conflict with what is being checked out.  (I tried to find a good reference and didn't.  I have seen them myself though.)

Since these usually happen when there is a conflict upon checkout, there are a couple of things I would look at for solving the issue.

1. Make sure that the files being checked out in your Jenkins workspace are not being modified.  If they are supposed to be modified by the process, you might want to look at this answer to [Force SVN checkout to overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312491/force-an-svn-checkout-command-to-overwrite-current-files).
2. Check the permissions of the directory vs. that of the user Jenkins is running under.

In general, Jenkins should be the owner and only manipulator of the workspace for any jobs it is running.