# SVN: how to checkout a repo and erase existing file/dir in the local repo

Tags: svn

I have a local copy of a repo (imported via checkout), I have added/modified some files/dir and I want to erase my local copy and all the modifications by the server copy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on your local thread

team -> disconnect

delete project

set the checkbox

go to your svn repo and check it new out

Comment: Great !!but Is it possible to do it in command I want to run automatically?

Comment: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312491/force-an-svn-checkout-command-to-overwrite-current-files?rq=1)